# Apache Kafka Streams API or Producer/Consumer APIs

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Hopefully this isn't too short-sighted of a question, but I have been struggling to comprehend how Apache Kafka works. I have been trying to create a streaming service that will take a simple pojo that is provided by a POST method, trigger a time window based on that pojo's timestamp, and provides a list of pojos that were also POSTed to the streaming service within that windowed timeframe.

I've been going through several different tutorials, and I've gotten to a point where I have a streaming service that has a custom Consumer and Producer factory and configs, and uses Spring annotations to listen to topics. So I can send and receive pojos with serialization with just the Consumer and Producer APIs.

Where I am having trouble is implementing the windowed time and a way to store the windowed records to provide. I am not sure whether to use just the Streams API, the Consumer/Producer APIs, or all of them together. I am trying to do this as a SpringBoot application. This is my first time tackling something like this and any kind of guidance or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: No doubt for me, use Kafka Streams.  KS provides you an simple interface for building the kind of application you want to do with transformations, joins, windowing operations ... Don't worry about consumer/producer api, KS will do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Producer and Consumer is used to push and pull data from the brokers, which makes it work like a messaging service. If you are going to use the standard Kafka Producer and Consumer, you might need to implement the streaming logic on your own.

However, with Kafka Streams, along with the messaging service capability, Kafka also handles the streaming logic for you, so that you can concentrate on your business logic.

So, I would suggest using Kafka Streams. You can also check out CEP (Continuous Event Processing) Engines which support windows and stream processing capabilities such as Esper and Siddhi.